# How to order by desc with 2 conditions in a query?

Tags: php, mysql

If there are 3 records with different amount as 500, 1000 and 1500 respectively, so for default query will be like amount order by DESC, 2nd condition is there is a button like "MOVE TO TOP",if 500 amount user click on button then that record move to top and next records should be display amount wise like 1500, 
1000.

If click on "move to top" button then current date will stored in click_date column.

I am using just default amount DESC query,

```
SELECT property_id 
FROM userpostproperties 
WHERE status = '1' 
ORDER BY amount DESC
```

Please suggest for further condition give me sample query

Comment: You should create a field `amount_order` where you can maintain amount order and use sorting according to that.

Comment: First of all, you need to add another field. Whatsoever it will be: `amount_order` like @urfusion said or marker `move_top`. Then all you need is proper sorting.

Comment: if click on "move to top" button then current date will stored in click_date coloumn

Comment: please give me sample query if you have

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `amount_order` field as suggested in the comment section and `order` by that. However, this might be an unfeasible option in case you do not want to store that information for some reason (memory saving, avoiding very frequent writes, etc.), then you could create a stored function which will do this calculation. However, if you do not know the ordering in advance, for instance because you need to order based on user actions, then you will need to write a PDO query and pass the ordering criteria as a parameter to that.